# How to find the inverse of a continuous linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T$ is in the set of bounded linear operators from $X$ to $X$ and norm of $T$ is less than 1. Use contraction mapping principle show $I-T$ is an isomorphism.(I can show it is one to one, but not onto and continuous inverse)

Comment: Hint: $(1-x)^{-1} = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots$ if $x \in (-1,1)$. Show that $$(I-T)(I + T + T^2 + \cdots) = I$$ if $\|T\| < 1$. The latter sum converging in the norm of ${\cal B}(X)$, of course.

Comment: I still dont see the hint

Comment: I will be more explicit. Show that $$S = I + T + T^2 + \cdots$$ converges in the operator norm. Then show that $(I-T)S = I$ so that $I-T$ has a right-sided inverse.

Comment: Actually $I-T$ is a linear homeomorphism by open mapping theorem.

Answer (score -1):

If $I -T$ is isomorphism if for all $y \in X$ there only one $x \in X$ such that
$$x - Tx = y$$
or equivalently, $x$ is the only fixed point of map $f_y : X \to X$ given for $f_y(z) = Tz + y$. But,
$$||f_y(z) - f_y(w)|| = ||Tz - Tw|| \leq ||T||||z - w||$$
that is, $f_y$ is a contraction and therefore has only one fixed point.

Comment: I dont think this helps

Comment: I'm only used contraction mapping principle show I−T is an isomorphism. The inverse you already showed.

Comment: it makes sense, and how do you show it is onto?

Comment: It's because $\forall y \in X$  there is only one $x in X$ such that $f_y(x) = x$, but $f_y(x)= x$, this is $Tx + y = x$, if only if $y = x -Tx$

Comment: sorry, my coment was wrong, how do you show the inverse is continuous?

Comment: Follows from a corollary of Theorem of Open Map, that if an  bounded linear aplication  between Banach space is bijective, then your inverse is  bounded.